# Verify multiple tables and copy data in ssis/BIML?

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, biml

I have a package that have about 6 to 7 dataflow tasks.Within  those dataflow tasks, I have up from 5 to 70 tasks thaht copy data from a source(ORACLE database) to a destination(sql database). I need to make to make a count of the source table and then if the source is not empty I will copy the data .I have presently a execute sql task taht trucate all the tables.I would like to truncate if my parameters is  > 0 .But wuth my use number of tables(177), I can't afford to use a variable for each one to hold the result of the count and then test the rest.Can I make something work with BIML.Can I use a stored procedure and loop throug it. I need some advice.

EDIT: ////

I think i did not explain myself correctly. I have multiple dataflow task with a lot of source to destination copy.In my control flow , I have an execute sql task that truncate all my 177 tables. I need to do a count on all the sources tables and store the results so i can send it to my execute sqltask.After thaht i want to check if my variable is > 0 then I would not do the task.Is there any easier way to do this than to create 177 variables.

Thanks.

Comment: BIML is only going to be of use if you decide to re-do the package. It's not a technology for editing existing packages (unless you buy the Mist tool to reverse engineer packages).

Comment: That said, there is no way to disable paths within a data flow. This is one of the many reasons to have data flows that are specifically focused on solving a business problem. Source(s) -> transformations -> Destination(s) You should be able to start at any source or destination and trace a path to every component inside the data flow. If you can't, then you should move the free floating items to a new data flow task

Comment: I think i did not explain myself correctly. I have multiple dataflow task with a lot of source to destination copy.In my control flow , I have an execute sql task that truncate all my 177 tables. I need to do a count on all the sources tables and store the results so i can send it to my execute sqltask.After thaht i want to check if my variable is > 0 then I would not do the task.Is there any easier way to do this than to create 177 variables.

Comment: You have two options:  re-engineer your entire package into BIML, then use BIML to create 177 individual variables. A lot of work to reverse engineer without Mist.  I would not do that.  Instead, create a single `Object` variable, and initialize it into a `Dictionary<string, int>` where string is your tablename and int is your count.  I realize you want the Execute SQL Task to store the count in a result set, but you're looking at a lot of work there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i'm not too late for you. You can use bimlonline.com to reverse engineer your package.

Bimlonline.com is free